# Errno::EISDIR in 'initialize' : Is a directory @ rb_sysopen - persistent.bak (Errno::EISDIR)

Tags: ruby

I am iterating through files in a folder to search for specific string.
There is a folder name as persistent.bak. While going through this folder, it is giving error... in 'initialize' : Is a directory @ rb_sysopen - persistent.bak (Errno::EISDIR).

```
Dir.glob("**/*.*") do |file_name|
    fileSdfInput = File.open(file_name)
    fileSdfInput.each_line do |line|
        if ((line.include?"DATE") 
            @count = @count + 1
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

your glob `Dir.glob("**/*.*")` matches the pattern *persistent.bak*
So inside your loop, you're actually trying to open the folder  named persistent.bak as a file, which ruby doesn't appreciate.

Just to convince yourself, try to output the file name, you'll see it.

Simplest workaround :

```
Dir.glob("**/*.*") do |file|
  next if File.directory? file
  fileSdfInput = File.open(file)
  fileSdfInput.each_line do |line|
    if (line.include?"DATE")
      @count = @count + 1
    end
  end
end
```